# XML ID missing on rule edition - Odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

I've tried in a xml file this code:

```
<record id="stock.stock_production_lot_rule" model="ir.rule">

    <field name="active" eval="False"/>

</record>
```

I don't have an error on the website, but since it didn't work, I checked the input log and found the error 'XML ID is missing'

> WARNING test odoo_tools_convert : Skipping deletion for missing XML ID 'stock_production_lot_rule'"

Yet the ID matches the one in the rule metadata.

I am on Odoo 14 Version Enterprise.

Here a screenshot of the rule metadata :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWj1f.png

****manifest**.py :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "stock_module_modifie",

    "version": "14.0",
    "author": "John",
    "website": "",
    "license": "AGPL-3",
    "category": "Vertical",
    "description": "Module Modèle",
    "depends": [
        'base',
        'stock',
    ],
    'data': [
        'views/stock_modification.xml',
    ],

    'demo': [
    ],
    'qweb': [
        
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application':True,
}
```

**stock_modification.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>  
    <record id="stock.stock_production_lot_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="active" eval="False"/>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Can you share the full XML source code and the __manifest__.py file ?

Comment: In the first example you don't have an ending `>`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error, maybe like said Kevin you had forgot an >

Comment: I don't have an error on the website, but since it didn't work, I checked the log and found the error 'XML ID is missing'

Comment: how did you inherit the stock module? did you do it right? any other things this module did?

Comment: I only give the id the rule which is show in the metadata of stock model. And no for now the module only do that.